# MongoDB Compass: How to select Distinct Values of a Field

Tags: json, mongodb, field, mongodb-compass, unique-values

I have a MongoDB database where each entry has a '**comment**' field. I'm using **MongoDB Compass** to connect to it, and trying to find all unique values of the '**comment**' field. I tried the following code in the '**Aggregations**' Tab of Compass (see image below), but I didn't get any result:

```
{$group: {
  _id: null,
  unique_comments: {
    $addToSet: comment
  }
}
```

An example of the data, in **JSON** format, is:

```
{"name":"Hannah Maxwell","date":"2020-01-07T20:16:13.931629-08:00","comment":"Maybe I like camping","location":{"latitude":43.81710433959961,"longitude":-79.42430114746094,"country":"CA","region":"ON"},"likes":1,"responses":24}
{"name":"Jordan Rodriguez","date":"2019-04-28T20:16:13.931629-07:00","comment":"I hate skiing","location":{"latitude":43.41518783569336,"longitude":-80.51475524902344,"country":"CA","region":"ON"},"likes":5,"responses":1}
{"name":"Bodhi Mckenzie","date":"2019-07-09T20:16:13.931629-07:00","comment":"I think I might like skiing","location":{"latitude":43.65549087524414,"longitude":-79.38555908203125,"country":"CA","region":"ON"},"likes":65,"responses":5}
```

[image: Image of MongoDB compass Aggregation Tab]

Comment: Have you tried: `$addToSet: "$comment"` ?

Comment: Yes, Micki, I just tried that, but it doesn't work. The "Preview" is still empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MongoDB Compass you need to pick the Aggregation Pipeline stage from the menu, try:

[image]

The preview data should get displayed on the right-hand side